# How to investigate client side WSAECONNABORTED happening very often only on machines with NVIDIA Quadro?

Tags: winsock, nvidia

We have a C++ client/server application in which the client retrieves and renders 3D content from a server.

Our client disconnects from the server very often (more than 50% of runs after less than 1 minute) with `recv` failing and `WSAGetLastError` returning `WSAECONNABORTED`. But the strange thing is that this happens only when:

- the client has an NVIDIA Quadro GPU (happening on multiple machines with various versions of Quadro)
- our application uses OpenGL for rendering

We didn't see this on a machine with another GPU. Switching to Direct3D for rendering also makes the disconnects go away. On one Quadro machine this started appearing (less often but still more than once a day) after a driver update pushed through Windows update. Reverting the driver helped.

The server also fails in `recv` with `WSAECONNRESET`. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326588/wsaeventselect-model/1329640#1329640) we are doing things wrong on the server side, where we indeed do `shutdown` and then immediately `close`. But since the server gets `WSAECONNRESET` I would say that the client forcibly disconnects first so the problem is not initiated by the server doing a bad close.

We'll probably fix the server `shutdown` + `close` problem in the long term but we would like some short term workaround or explanation for the behavior on Quadros. Maybe it's a driver bug that somehow interacts with Winsock, even though it sounds very wacky.

**Am I right that server `WSAECONNRESET` means that the client disconnected first?**

**Any ideas on how to troubleshoot potential weird bugs that the GPU driver would cause to sockets?** I don't expect a specific solution to our weird problem of course, but any idea would do.

Comment: I have an eerily similar problem: C++ app on Windows 7, client is drawing OpenGL with a Quadro video card, does `recv()` gets `WSAECONNABORTED`.  The problem is very sensitive to timing.  Running in a debugger it's never reproducible, debug version is harder to reproduce.  I suspect the Quadro connection is merely that it does the drawing faster than  other pipelines allowing the timing necessary to hit this.  Microsoft has a KB + hotfix for a similar issue for Win2003: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925513

Comment: Additional note: A WireShark trace confirms client is to blame, sending RST first.

Comment: [This link](http://www.sockets.com/err_lst1.htm#WSAECONNABORTED) gives a bit more helpful information than [Microsoft's list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and suggests you may not be emptying your buffers fast enough.  Checking a Wireshark trace in my case does show the client window size steadily shrinking before winsock returns WSAECONNABORTED..

Comment: Did this ever get sorted? I'm seeing similar disconnects in a java program that uses opengl and sockets, but only on windows and only with quadro cards. In my case wireshark shows the client sending a RST too, but I don't see a shrinking window size.

Comment: @sqweek I, at least, didn't get it sorted

Comment: @sqweek, not sorted here, but worked around by copying data that's passed to the NVIDIA driver into a global buffer.  Suspicion: alignment or pointer lifetimes to blame.  Will post more if I get time to look at it more deeply.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the client is issuing a close/shutdown with unread data still in the receive buffer? This will abort the connection.